# Run existing Macro only on Selected Cells, instead of the whole sheet

Tags: vba, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have the following macro (LibreOffice Calc):

```
Sub CalcFindAndReplace
    Dim oDoc,aFind,aReplace,aRayCount,FandR,oSheet
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    aFind = Array("Mecanica","Cancion","Murcielago")
    aReplace = Array("Mecánica","Canción","Murciélago")
    aRayCount = 0
    oSheet = oDoc.getSheets.getByName(oDoc.CurrentSelection.Spreadsheet.Name)
    FandR = oSheet.createReplaceDescriptor
    FandR.SearchCaseSensitive = true
    FandR.SearchWords = true ' 1 to A but not 11 to AA
    FandR.SearchRegularExpression = true

    While aRayCount <= uBound(aFind)
        FandR.setSearchString(aFind(aRayCount))
        FandR.setReplaceString(aReplace(aRayCount))
        aRayCount = aRayCount + 1
        oSheet.ReplaceAll(FandR)
    End While

End Sub
```

It works fine, but I need to add it the ability to be applied only on manual selections of cells (different each time), not on all the cells of the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED

The following code will take the currently selected cells, will replace each cell with the actual String value (beware: a calc function that may act on a cell will removed permanently) and then will replace the strings cells as desired.

Motivated by http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=137064 and http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=71015 and http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=65318 ...

```
Sub ReplaceEachCellWithActualValue()
    ' Gets the current user selection and replace each cell with the actual String value
    Dim oDoc, oSheet, oCell As Object
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oSheet = oDoc.getSheets.getByName(oDoc.CurrentSelection.Spreadsheet.Name)
    RangeAddress = oDoc.getCurrentSelection.getRangeAddress 

    c1 = RangeAddress.StartColumn
    r1 = RangeAddress.StartRow
    c2 = RangeAddress.EndColumn
    r2 = RangeAddress.EndRow

    for i = c1 to c2
            for j = r1 to r2 
                    Dim cellasstring As String
                    oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(i, j)
                    cellasstring = oCell.string
                    oSheet.getCellByPosition(i, j).String = cellasstring
            next j
    next i

End Sub

Sub CalcFindAndReplace

    ' first replace all formulas on the selected cells with actual strings...
    ReplaceEachCellWithActualValue()

    ' Then replace as desired...  
    Dim oDoc,aFind,aReplace,aRayCount,FandR,oSheet        
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    aFind = Array("Mecanica","Cancion","Murcielago")
    aReplace = Array("Mecánica","Canción","Murciélago")
    aRayCount = 0
    oSheet = oDoc.getSheets.getByName(oDoc.CurrentSelection.Spreadsheet.Name)
    FandR = oSheet.createReplaceDescriptor
    FandR.SearchCaseSensitive = true
    FandR.SearchWords = true ' 1 to A but not 11 to AA
    FandR.SearchRegularExpression = true

    Dim oSelection as Object
    oSelection = oDoc.CurrentController.getSelection

    While aRayCount <= uBound(aFind)
        FandR.setSearchString(aFind(aRayCount))
        FandR.setReplaceString(aReplace(aRayCount))
        oSelection.ReplaceAll(FandR) 
        aRayCount = aRayCount + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked perfect with cells containing text, but didn't work on cells whose contents are the result of a formula, which would be what I need most.

Comment: ok, there is a workaround if you do not need the calc function that result in that string for future use. Check the improved answer.

Comment: Working almost perfect.

If the term to replace is alone in the cell, it works.
For example:
'Mecanica': it changes to 'Mecánica'.

If the term to replace, is accompanied by other characters in the cell, it doesn't work.
For example:
'Naranja Mecanica 2': it doesn't change.

Comment: Actually, it seems that you need to call [SUBSTITUTE](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUBSTITUTE_function) function from inside a macro something that you can achieve by combining the above code and the code in [this post](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=65318). However, this seems to be a different question.